# How many times was the nine tailed fox used to attack the leaf village?

Tags: naruto

Since the beginning of *Naruto*, I know that the fourth Hokage (his father) had sealed the nine tailed fox into Naruto. But now I am at the part where Madara Uchiha comes into play and I understand that he used his Sharingan to control the beast and attacked the leaf village.

So was the nine-tailed fox used 2 times to attack the leaf village, during the first and fourth Hokage?

Answer (score 3):

We can use deduction to answer this with a few givens: the Leaf was created by Madara so it didn’t exist before him, and extracting a Bijuu kills its host, even Uzumakis (it just takes a little longer).

Okay, so going from that, we know that Madara was the first attack, that makes one. In response to the Madara attack, the first Hokage put the Kyuubi into his wife, Mito Uzumaki. We also know that it was directly given to Kushina Uzumaki from Mito. This means it never left Mito because she would’ve already been dead. While Kushina was in possession of the Kyuubi, it was extracted by Madara again, the second attack. Immediately after, it was given to Naruto, and 12 years later the events of Naruto began.

Thus, we can conclude that the Nine Tails was used to attack the Leaf exactly 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler: Madara did not attack the second time. The attacker was someone using his name. You could say he was acting on his behalf. So, twice.

Comment: Normally, we use the spoiler tag for spoilers, just out of courtesy to other users who may not have yet seen the show. It’s mostly in the clear since this has been common knowledge for 5 or so years, but just so you know. :)